# ¿Como agregar un componente con "innerHTML"?

Tags: vue.js

estoy intentando la forma de agregar un componente con "innerHTML", básicamente mi código es este:

```
elemento.innerHTML = '<miComponente></miComponente>'
```

Al parecer esta no es la forma de hacerlo, por que lo agrega como tal, Vue no renderiza, hay alguna forma de poder realizar esto?.

Espero sea suficiente la información

Comment: Esto que deseas lograr es con JS puro o a través de VueJS?

Comment: Porque lo quieres hacer con innerHTML? Deseas agregar componentes dinámicamente?

Answer (score -1):

Te recomniendo que uses estas comillas `` en vez de ''
y también te recomiendo que uses v-show ó v-if para mostrar otros componentes, ya que no es buena práctica agregar un componente de forma dinámica de esa forma...
Ej.

```
<div>
    <div v-if="ctrl">
        muchas letras
    </div>
    <tuComponente v-else></tuComponente>
</div>
```

ctrl es una variable, en este caso booleano

Comment: Cuál sería la diferencia o beneficio de usar estás comillas sobre las otras?

Comment: Que actualmente se usa esas comillas y los beneficios son que puedes agregar código con renglón saltado, en cambio con '' solo puedes agregar todo lo que esta en una línea de código

Comment: La respuesta seria v-if o v-show... y tu código no funciona por que no puedes mezclar javascript en vuejs por mas que sea framework hecho con javascript...